# knockout with dynamic viewmodels

Tags: ajax, viewmodel, knockout.js

There's a ton of info on the interwebs about how to handle dynamic views (via ajax calls) with Knockout, but is there a best practice for dynamic viewmodels?

For instance, say I have a single page app that renders (via ajax) different types of forms (with different input fields) based on role, user choices, contexts, etc.  Not only would I use templates for each form, but I'd like to do the same for the viewmodel, since each viewmodel may have many very different properties and it wouldn't be practical to have one massive viewmodel for every possible template.

I'm a bit of a rookie with ko, and it may not be meant to be used in this fashion.  Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A popular way to do this type of thing is to have a main view model that hosts sub-view models.

Here is a really basic example of defining "model" objects that have a template and associated data.

```
function Model(key, template, data) {
   this.key = key;
   this.template = ko.observable(template);
   this.data = data; 
}

var viewModel = {
   models: ko.observableArray([
       new Model("user", "userTmpl", { first: "Bob", last: "Smith" }),
       new Model("item", "itemTmpl", { name: "MyItem", description: "Here are some details" })
   ]),
   selectedModel: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then, you could use it like:

```
<select data-bind="options: models, optionsText: 'key', optionsCaption: 'select a model...', value: selectedModel"></select>

<hr />

<div data-bind="with: selectedModel">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: template(), data: data }"></div>    
</div>


<script id="userTmpl" type="text/html">
    <span data-bind="text: last"></span>, <span data-bind="text: first"></span>
</script>

<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <div data-bind="text: description"></div>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/29kWf/

Obviously, you wouldn't likely bind the selection of the model in a select, but it helps show how it can work.  Rather than an array your models could be an object with the property names matching the key.

The "data" in the "model" objects would be your sub-view models.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I think I'm beginning to see KO more clearly.  Would it be correct to use this methodology with the addition of the KO Mapping plugin to bind the data (first, last, name, description, etc) as observables?  In my scenerio I'm pulling the data via ajax. In fact, if I end up pulling both the templates and the data via ajax, I should be able to just make a call to 'applyBindings' in the Success callback to hook everything up - correct?  I'll give this a go over the weekend when I have some time to spare.

Comment: Definitely fine to use the mapping plugin with this idea.  Calling `applyBindings` in the success callback is fine.  You really only want to call it one time, unless you are passing in the second parameter to restrict it to a certain element and are only doing multiple calls to against elements that are not descendants. 
Otherwise, in the sample that I provided, you can call applyBindings up front and until selectedModel is populated, nothing will actually get bound.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Facing the same problem.

Try [Knockout Namespaces](https://github.com/hunterloftis/knockout.namespaces)